# Discord.py - Exporting code from pycharm for selling

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a business out of my discord.py skills. I have made a discord.py bot and want to export it from pycharm to be able to sell it on a site like fiverr. Does someone know how I could do that? (I am an absolute noob at this, pls help me anyone...)

Comment: You might want to learn about packaging, 'export' is just copy-pasting a file, and is great for friends but not really a business model (you might be able to charge a few bucks, but for something serious or costly "code wants to be free", and) you will have trouble monetizing in the way you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many ways of doing such, you could copy & paste, but it isn't the most professional nor efficient way of doing things, you could send them a link to a private GitHub repository, or else send them the folder with the source files and whatever other files needed. There's plenty of ways of doing it. You will need to find out what works best for you and your client(s).